# Replacing a combination switch to two separate switches (1. Simple light switch and 1 smart switch)

Tags: switch, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I have an outdoor light that I would like to control with a smart switch and a hallway light that can be a simple switch. Previously, the two were controlled by a non-smart combination switch;

I would like them to be two separate switches. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to wire it.

I have restated the question to be more concise please find the diagram below of the problem.

I hope this is enough information for everyone. Please let me know if you need more information.

[image]

***Update***

Below is an adaption on @Ruskus design, however when I supply power, only the Out door lamp gets power. I am suspecting the single pole switch is bad, unless my wiring is also incorrect.

***Update Update

My adaptation of Ruskus design works, I did have a bad single pole switch

[image]

Comment: words words words, make a simple hand drawing photo it and paste here

Comment: How many switches do you have in the old design. Do they have 3 wires each ? Could you independently control the lights inside and outside?

Comment: In previous design there was a combination switch (two switches combined into one gang) that were able to control the lights indepently

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box involved please?

Comment: Before you do anything find the circuit barker and turn if off. Black wires are usually load, the white is neutral. The red is for bridge between the switches. The single pole switch black screw is for ground.

Comment: @Ruskes Breaker is off.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel pictures are attached. let me know if you need more/different

Comment: Where does the NM cable on the right side of the opening lead? Also, what happened to the switch box that was there...or was there not a switch box there to begin with?!

Comment: The 2-wire NM I believe runs to the outdoor light, where it terminates. It was in a metal single gang box, I removed it. I have purchased a double gang box but I have been fiddling with this all day so I figured I would figure out the correct wiring and then put it in a box.

Comment: what is the smart switch going to control ?

Comment: @Ruskes the outdoor light

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel do you need more info?

Comment: Do you know which one is the hot wire, mark it with tape, that would be the incoming hot. You will need it on bth switches.

Comment: The cable with 2 wires (Black+ White) is your incoming (from the circuit barker) The cable in the right back corner is going out to the outside light (also has black and white). The cable with 3 wires (Black+ White + Red) is going to your indoor lamp. For now ignore the red and tape it.

Comment: How was it wired before?  That's important, colors don't mean all that much.

Comment: Could you re-phrase that, please?

Are you trying to control the outdoor and hallway lights with the same switch - which is what your Question appears to be Asking?

Otherwise, what, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try this based on my drawing

Ignore the red (Tape it) in the 3 wire cable

As usual the polarity for the lamps does not matter.
The incoming is your fancy isolation cable with 2 wires.

[image: lamp]